# Oracle не хочет использовать NLS_LANG

Tags: oracle, ssrs

Суть проблемы:
Есть сервер Windows Server 2016 и 2019. На обоих установлен SQLServerReportingServices. Для организации отчетов из базы Oracle устанавливаю ODAC121024_x64. В запросах формат даты (выбор периода отчета) 2019.11 (через точку). Все работает отлично, отчеты выгружаются. Ровно до первой перезагрузки сервера. После перезагрузки ошибка:

> Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException:
>   Не удалось выполнить запрос для набора данных "MainDataSet". --->
>   Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException: ORA-01722: invalid
>   number

Устанавливал локаль на америку, сервер английского языка, формат английский, NLS_LANG прописан в AMERICAN_AMERICA.CL8MSWIN1251. Но ничего не помогает. Удаляешь клиента, устанавливаешь заново - все работает. После ребута - опять ошибка. Есть одно решение - использовать формат даты в запросах с запятой т.е. 2019,11 но тогда придется переписывать все отчеты, да к тому же при NLS_LANG америки, и так должно ведь использоваться точка для разделения десятичной части. А используется запятая, и ни в какую не хочет применяться точка.
P.S. на сервере Oracle11g. Я использую 12-ю версию ODAC, т.к. при установке 11-й версии, ругается что сервер отчетов не совместим с данной версией.

Пример запроса: `select sum from sr_opl o where o.ym=:ym`
где :ym - это char в формате 2019.01. В наборе данных "MainDataSet" как раз и есть вышеуказанный запрос.

o.ym идет из другого датасета(выборка дат), где идет выборка данных, она явно конвертируемая: `SELECT to_char(ym_add(MAX (ym), 1),'9999.99') ym FROM calc WHERE  ym &gt;= 2006.10` - и этот запрос идет нормально. а вот когда эта выборка дат вставляется уже в запрос чуть выше - то проблема. Если править "MainDataSet" - то это более 700 отчетов, а запрос бывает по 300 строк. 
Другой вопрос, почему после установки ODAC поверх существующего, той же версии, в ту же директорию, ничего не меняя, начинает все работать. Но ровно до перезагрузки сервера.

Нашел версию, на которую сервер не ругается (ODAC112040Xcopy_64bit). Результат абсолютно одинаковый. NLS_LANG в системных переменных прописан:
[image: В системные переменные все прописано]

Comment: Вы можете воспроизвести проблему? Привидите в вопросе пример входных данных и получаемого результата. Где вы устанавливаете NLS_LANG?

Comment: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Oracle\KEY_myhome - так названа ветка с клиентом ODAC, там и установлен NLS_LANG. Также устанавливал в системных переменных (Свойства системы - дополнительно - переменные среды).

Comment: Нашел еще одну особенность - ставишь клиента ODAC еще раз (прямо поверх). С первого раза ничего не получается, ставишь еще раз - и все работает. До перезагрузки системы. После перезагрузки системы можно установить еще 2 раза и опять заработает.

Comment: Как воркароунд - конвентируйте значение `o.ym` явно, как-то так: `to_char (o.ym, 'FM9999D99', 'nls_numeric_characters = ''.,''')`. Почему NLS_LANG не доходит, пока в вопросе мало информации.

Comment: to_char используется, конвертация тоже идет. Но если править с `'nls_numeric_characters = ''.,''')`, то это править более 700 отчетов((

Comment: 1) Почему  после установки ODAC может читать NLS_LANG из реестра, а после  перезагрузки больше не читает то, что было записано ранее, можете спросить у разработчиков ODAC. 2) Установите системную переменную окружения NLS_LANG. Она перепишет установки из реестра. Если не поможет, то вы её просто не там устанавливаете и обратитесь к сисадминам.

Comment: В том то и дело, все установлено...

Answer (score -1):

Исходящие данные формировались как положено, это факт.
Проблема была с входящими данными.
Как оказалось, клиенту ODAC (или самому серверу SSRS?), абсолютно плевать параметры, прописанные в реестр и системные переменные. Исходя из того, что при установке ОС был выбран регион Россия, хоть все языковое пространство и было на Английском - клиент оракла брал данные именно из системных переменных профиля пользователя.
Для этого, необходимо зайти на сервер под учетными данными, которые запускают SSRS, и прописать формат даты и локацию на United States. После перезагрузки все заработало как надо.
[image: Региональные настройки]

**Update:** Все-таки проблема не решилась.. Серверу по-прежнему плевать на все настройки... После перезагрузки, при просмотре параметров сессии: NLS_LANGUAGE, NLS_TERRITORY и т.д. опять всатает в формат RUSSIA :(

Comment: _Серверу по-прежнему плевать на все настройки_ - серверу не плевать, он  делает то, что ему говорят, он знать не может, где находится клиент. Проблема на стороне клиента. Если вы можете посмотреть настрийки сессии, то почему вы не можете попрообовать их изменить с `altter session ...`? И раз ответ не решил проблему, то стоит дополнить вопрос, а ответ удалить.